# Delete data from multiple table using one command synchronously

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I am using **mySql** database and I have three tables  **Product**, **Producer** and **Supplier**

I want to delete data from all the tables just by providing the *product_id*
and delete data in specific order i.e... first,**Product** should be deleted then **Producer** and then **Supplier**.

means i want to combine the following three queries

```
delete from product where product_id = 2
delete from producer where product_id = 2
delete from supplier where product_id =2
```

Comment: You might want to solve this using foreign key constraints on those tables.

Comment: Check this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make the `product_id` a  foreign key in the `Producer` and `Supplier` tables.  This foreign key would refer back to the `producer_id` primary key in the `Product` table.  Then, deleting a product record would automatically delete the linked records in the other two tables.

The `Producer` table, for example, might look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Producer (
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES Product (product_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use multi delete

```
DELETE product, produce, supplier FROM product, producer, supplier WHERE product.product_id = 2 and supplier.product_id = 2 and producer.product_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Without foreign keys and on delete cascade set, your best option is to string them together into a single statement by placing a semi-colon at the end of each one.

```
delete from product where product_id = 2; delete from producer where product_id = 2; delete from supplier where product_id =2;
```

Comment: actually, it has foreign key constraints, how can I delete the data